# C++ stringstream, if word is numeric, divide by two

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am fairly new to programming and have to create a program which reads the prompt: "I have 8 dollars to spend."  It then needs to print out with each word on a separate line, and then if any of the strings is numeric, it needs to be divided by 2.  Therefore it should end up printing out as:

```
I
have
4
dollars
to
spend.
```

I have managed to do everything, except finding the numeric value and dividing it by 2.  So far I have this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
string prompt;
string word;

cout << "Prompt: ";

getline(cin, prompt);

stringstream ss;
ss.str(prompt);

while (ss >> word)
{
cout << word << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

After looking through various other posts, I cannot manage to get this to work.  I'm assuming its an if/else statement within the while loop along the lines of, if numeric, set int num to num / 2 then cout << num << endl;, else cout << word << endl;, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the stringstream class, which handles conversions between strings and other data types, to attempt to convert a given string to a number. If the attempt is successful, you know 
The stringstream object allows you to treat a string as though it is a stream similar to cin or cout.

Incorporate this into your while loop, like so:

```
while (ss >> word)
{
int value = 0;
stringstream convert(word); //create a _stringstream_ from a string
//if *word* (and therefore *convert*) contains a numeric value,
//it can be read into an _int_
if(convert >> value) { //this will be false if the data in *convert* is not numeric
  cout << value / 2 << endl;
}
else
  cout << word << endl;

}
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much, that worked.  I actually tried something nearly identical to that, except I didn't include stringstream convert(word);.  Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The `strtol` (C++11 version that works on `std::string` directly: `std::stol`) function is really good for testing whether a string holds a number, and if so, what the numeric value is.

Or you could continue using iostreams like you have been... try extracting a number (`int` or `double` variable), and if that fails, clear the error bit and read a string.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have 50 rep so I cant comment, thats why I'm writing it as answer.
I think you can check it character by character, using Ascii value of each char, & if there are ascii values representing numbers between two spaces(two \n in this case as you've already seperated each word), then you have to divide the number by 2.